# Выбор области разработки

Tags: path, big-data

Здравствуйте.
Мне интересна высшая математика. 
Где ещё она используется в разработке помимо Big Data?

Comment: Вы не обижайтесь, но как бы вы ответили, если б программист сказал, что хочет стать фармацевтом, в школе хорошо знал химию...? Причем лекарства в ампулах раздражают, а интересует *волнение* таблеток...

Comment: Вопрос - оффтопик а сайте, надо закрыть. По теме: начните с позиций начального уровня. 1. Ждать, пока доучишься можно бесконечно, начинайте с чего есть. 2 не распыляйтесь, вам и так будет сложно с резкой сменой профессии.

Comment: Harry, Я бы указал на опечатки и посоветовал бы переформулировать на вопрос по существу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы выбрал работу джуниором. Там и покажут как надо и даже денег заплатят. А математику сколько не учи, все равно не выучишь все те вещи, которые понадобятся. Зато времени можно потратить очень много.

Лучше учить ее по мере поступления задач.